# Any benefits of using Windows Communication Foundation/ Web Services vs. a simple .aspx page for simple Desktop app-to-server communication?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm working on a VB6 app that will do some very simple communication with a web server (passing  value and getting back an anwer. Low bandwith and infrequent use).

[Someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915129/suggestions-pointers-for-post-get-to-an-asp-or-aspx-page-from-a-desktop-app/2915142#2915142) using WCF or Web Services. I'm wondering what the advantages are vs. just posting to an ASPX page like:

Myserver.com/Functions.ASP?FunctionName=GetValue?UserName=BubbGump
and returning some simple, easy to parse text, like one value per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Introduction to WCF in ASP.NET and VB.NET](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/introduction-to-wcf-vb.aspx) has this tidbit about it:

> WCF (or Windows Communication
>   Foundation) is a union of technologies
>   developed by Microsoft to make it
>   easier and quicker for developers to
>   build distributed applications. WCF
>   builds on the existing technologies of
>   ASMX, .NET Remoting, MSMQ and DCOM.
>   WCF attempts to unify these
>   technologies and harness the power of
>   all, while simplifying the process of
>   implementation.

[Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation](http://aspalliance.com/1103_introduction_to_windows_communication_foundation) from ASP Alliance notes the following:

> Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF), codenamed Indigo in Microsoft,
>   is the last generation of service
>   oriented technologies for development.
>   It provides all the latest means to
>   help developers build service oriented
>   applications.  The result of service
>   oriented design is a distributed
>   system which runs between services and
>   clients.  Windows Communication
>   Foundation is Microsoft infrastructure
>   for Service Oriented architecture.
>
> You have probably worked with Web
>   Services in .NET 1.x or 2.0 and may
>   have some experiences with Remoting. 
>   Windows Communication Foundation is an
>   enhanced technology to provide the
>   same functionality with better
>   features and reduces the time to
>   develop a distributed system.  Web
>   Services and Services are not
>   identical.  One main difference is Web
>   Services use HTTP protocol, but
>   Services can use any protocol and this
>   is an important difference.

Lastly, if you do use URLs, then

```
Myserver.com/Functions.ASP?FunctionName=GetValue?UserName=BubbGump
```

should be

```
Myserver.com/Functions.ASP?FunctionName=GetValue&UserName=BubbGump
```

as the ? is notes the end of the URL while the & is the delimiter on the querystring key/value pairs.  Another point is that WCF doesn't require requests to go through IIS which may be of interest in some ways as there can be issues there.  Classic ASP can have numerous problems especially if there are those "On Error Resume Next" lines that make the requests go into a zombie mode of just running until the machine crashes completely.

Answer (score 0):

WCF / WebServices is the 'proper' way to do it...  You get all the communication infrastructure, stability, fault catching, etc.  but there's nothing wrong with the ASP approach that you're suggesting.

When you've implemented your ASP solution and start to see points where you want that something more, then you'll know it's time to move to WCF.

It'll be a more natural progression that way, and the transition may be easier.

Comment: What sorts of problems scenarios might WFC/WebServices avoid?

E.g., some of the gotchas I can see are:
-Internet unavailable
-Delay while PC dials up the internet
-Delay or "limbo" state while waiting for user to respond to Firewall "do you want to allow" msg.
-Server down
-Web page unavailable

What we're implementing is fault tolerant (phone-home registration system).  So the only ones above that seem problematic are the "limbo" state and possibly the slow dialing internet just b/c the app is left "hung" waiting for a response.